# session or request scope variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, guice

I would like to have a scoped variable in Spring. In Guice it is very simple:

```
@Singleton
class MyBean
{
    @Inject @Named("session-scoped")
    private Provider<Integer> someString;
    void doSomething()
    {
        // returns a random number for a current session.
        // Each user session should generate new number,
        // but one session should keep the same number.
        Integer n1 = someString.get();
        Integer n2 = someString.get();
        assert n1 == n2;
    }
}
...
class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
    ...
    }

    @Provides
    @SessionScoped
    @Named("session-scoped") Integer someString()
    {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
}
```

How could I do something similar in Spring?

Keep in mind, it is java.lang.Integer, not some user bean, it could not be aop-proxied.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need session scope. You just need a singleton custom provider instance

```
interface CustomProvider<E> {
    public E get();
}

@Configuration
class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public CustomProvider<Integer> factory() {
        return new CustomProvider<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer get() throws BeansException {
                return new Random().nextInt();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And inject it

```
@Inject
private CustomProvider<Integer> factory;
```

I missed that you wanted the same value for the session. [See Emerson's answer for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653878/438154)

---

In general for session scoped beans:

In a `@Configuration` class, you can provide a `@Bean` method that has session scope.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION /* or simply "session" */)
public SomeBean someBean() {
    return new SomeBean();
}
```

You can use the `@Scope` annotation on a `@Component` annotated class as well.

In XML

```
<bean id="someBean" class="com.example.SomeBean" scope="session" />
```

Comment: And how to use it? Could you show injection point? Keep in mind, it is `java.lang.String`, not SomeBean, it could not be proxied.

Comment: @kan Ah I didn't see that. Let me get back to you.

Comment: @kan I think this is the best you can do. Matches what you do in Guice.

Comment: Umm, he does need session scope to get the same value within the same session. Adding an answer using your provider.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia Ah, should have read the comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class IntegerProvider implements Provider<Integer> {

   private Integer value = new Random().nextInt();

   public Integer get() {
       return this.value;
   }
}
```

...

```
@Autowired
private Provider<Integer> integerProvider;
```

...

```
assert this.integerProvider.get().equals(this.integerProvider.get();
```

Comment: It is the best I've done myself already, but I am forced to cache value in a Provider... In more complex scenario - value is calculated from other injected beans I could not do initialization in constructor, it looks worse, I need add multithreading safety.

Comment: It sounds like your domain model isn't strong enough. Ask yourself "What do these values mean?" "Why are they session scoped?" "How are they related?" etc. If you can model them as an entity object (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html) then you can make that object a bean with session scope, inject it wherever you need it, and let other beans mutate it.

Comment: I don't like that Spring is so intrusive, it dictates how should I design domain model. At the moment it is just a cached parameter, if it becomes more clear how it should be in a domain model, I refactor it, but because of spring I should overcomplicate my design, guice is much more better, it is flexible enough to not pollute my classes with boilerplate code and its own guts.

Comment: BTW, the approach with `Provider<Integer>` just doesn't work for me, spring autowires its own `DefaultListableBeanFactory.DependencyProvider` class, which then lazily looks up for `Integer` types in the context, not noticing `Provider<Integer>` as it fails to support generics as I understand. So, I should  create `CustomIntegerProvider` rubbish classes. I hate the Spring already.

Comment: re: `Provider`, I assumed that was your own class, my answer was just a follow up of @sotirios-delimanolis's `CustomProvider`. re: generics, Spring does support autowiring of classes with generic types, assuming you're on Spring 4. re: your domain model, my point was to think about what you're doing; you're effectively injecting a magic integer by name. That's a "global variable" code smell, whether you're using Guice, Spring, or whatever. `Integer` is also a final object, preventing the container from building proxies to bridge session and singleton scopes.

Comment: No, I have Spring 3... not sure how soon I could upgrade, but I rather upgrade from Spring to Guice. It is not "global", it is context specific, IoC easily allows to change scope, and it is not "variable", but a lazy constant which should be initialised once for each context. You could consider it as a primitive parameter, shared by several beans and loaded expensively (say by SOAP call). Final objects are nearly always good, and it is Spring limitation, proxying is usually available for `javax.inject.Provider`, Guice works perfectly for this case.